# How can I unlock the background layer in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers

Why is the background layer in Photoshop locked?
I always have to create a copy and delete the original one.

Is there a setting to start a new project with unlocked background layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just Double-click on it and give a name like "a".

Comment: Thanks for this - I have had this question for some time now...  Yee haw!

Answer (score 0):

Simply hold <kbd>ALT</kbd> and double click the layer.

This probably only works for older versions of Photoshop though, but since OP doesn't state what version, I've included it, plus, it's easy to try yourself.